# JQuery is not working because Mootools is already loaded in joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, frameworks, mootools

I tried to include the JQuery lib into joomla but it's not working. Many comps and modules use mootools inside my CMS. I think the problem is a conflict between the two frameworks.

I have searched the internet and found some articles but the following code is still not working as expected.

```
<?php
JHTML::stylesheet('demo_page.css', 'media/system/css/');
JHTML::stylesheet('ftab.css', 'media/system/css/');
JHTML::stylesheet('demo_table.css', 'media/system/css/');
$option="com_mycomp";
$base=JUri::root().'components/'.$option.'/js/';
$document=&JFactory::getDocument();
$noConflict="jQuery.noConflict();";
//$document->addScriptDeclaration($noConflict);
$document->addScriptDeclaration("jQuery(document).ready(function($){jQuery('#example').dataTable();});");
JHTML::script('jquery.js',$base,true);
$document->addScript($base,'jquery.js');
$document->addScript($base,'jquery.dataTables.js');
?>
```

This should sort my table using JQuery but it does not.

How do I use mootools and jQuery concurrently in joomla ?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading your code, I see this:

```
$noConflict="jQuery.noConflict();";
//$document->addScriptDeclaration($noConflict);
$document->addScriptDeclaration("jQuery(document).ready(function($){jQuery('#example').dataTable();});");
JHTML::script('jquery.js',$base,true);
$document->addScript($base,'jquery.js');
$document->addScript($base,'jquery.dataTables.js');
```

but it should look like this:

```
JHTML::script('jquery.js',$base,true);
$document->addScript($base,'jquery.js');
$document->addScript($base,'jquery.dataTables.js');
$noConflict="jQuery.noConflict();";
//$document->addScriptDeclaration($noConflict);
$document->addScriptDeclaration("jQuery(document).ready(function($){jQuery('#example').dataTable();});");
```

Now, here's why:

Javascript is interpreted in the order it comes to the page. The page is being told to use jQuery.noConflict() and the jQuery datatable, before it knows what those things are.

Comment: Thanks you very much @jcolebrand! It really helped me to fix my this problem!

Comment: then I `discommmented //$document->addScriptDeclaration($noConflict); `line

Comment: In addition could you please tell me how to add attribute to <body> tag in joomla using JHTML. I need to change its class like that `<body id="dt_example" class="ex_highlight_row">`

Comment: two comments: I don't know Joomla enough to know how to tell you that, but jQuery could do it easily enough once the page has loaded (there's only ever one <body> tag) ... If the answer did help you, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work